# Firebase deploy doesn't include bower_components

Tags: bower, firebase-hosting

I was just trying publish my website based on firebase using firebase deploy.

However, after the deployment succeeds, when I access the website, I notice in the console everything under bower_components folder fails to load.

How should I fix that? I am not sure how firebase deployment works, and I looked up online with no avail.